# website need to redirected to https://www

Tags: magento-1.9

Site URL is https://www.spam.com/  but unfortunately it works with https://spam.com/.

**This is wrong.** can anyone suggested me how we can redirect to https://www.spam.com/

Comment: create rule in .htacess file

Comment: could you please delete questions like this???

Comment: Look your DNS and .htaccess rules @Pratik Kamani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^detectachem.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.detectachem.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Place this code in htacess for more information refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 4):

This is also workable solution for nginx server where you can't modified .htaccess file.
Please go to Database and check table name `core_config_data`, under column 'path' check

> web/unsecure/base_url
>
> web/secure/base_url

Change that rows value to specific url would you like to make for your website.

"Don't Forgot to refresh cache and indexing".

Answer (score 0):

Changing the unsecured base URL to https will change all links and redirect non-https requests to https://example.com/ (the homepage) because that's what Magento does when the base URL validation fails.

So this is a good start but to also redirect http://example.com/foo/ to https://example.com/foo/ you need to do it via web server redirect.

For example, add the following code at the top of your .htaccess:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Or if you use a reverse proxy like Varnish:

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
This is because the requests from Varnish to Magento will be without SSL (HTTP), but Varnish sets the X-Forwarded-Proto header to "https" if the original request was made with SSL (HTTPS).